# Automatic date formatting according to excel's language setting

Tags: vba, excel-formula, date-formatting

```
=TEXT(TODAY()-DAY(TODAY())+1,"MMM-JJ")
```

This formula is written in excel for reading today's month and year and then adding next month in the next row.

But this only works when the excel's language setting is in German and doesn't work for the Excel sheet whose language setting is in English.

So, what can I do that it should work for both English and German language setting.

I tried by adding country codes available in excel built-in, but it is not working.

Comment: So this MONTH(TODAY())+1 gives 8 as the result, compared to MONTH(TODAY()) which gives 7. Then you can format the 8 or the 7 as you wish as these functions are using the serial number.

Answer (score 1):

**Don't write any *strings* that looks like a date into a cell. Write real *dates* into a cell.**

When you want to see the date in format "MMM-YY", use the number format to *format* the cell. If one day you (or your boss) changes your mind because you want to see now also the day, or you want to see the year with 4 digits, just adapt the number format - the *value* remains unchanged.

The formula is simple: `=TODAY()`. The number format is also simple: `MMM-YY`
If you are on a german Excel, you maybe have to enter `MMM-JJ` instead, but when you open this Workbook on a computer with different regional settings, the format is understood correctly, because internally, Excel stores it as `MMM-YY` (you can prove that using VBA).

The formula for the cell having the next month is also easy: `=EDATE(TODAY(),1)` (depending on your regional settings, you might have to enter `=EDATE(TODAY();1)` instead). Of course, format that cell also using the number format you want.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I want the formatting to be done auomatically. I mean to say that I don't want the user (irrespective of the excel sheet's language setting) to keep changing the format everytime.
so can you please tell me the formula for doing so?

Comment: I don't understand: The formatting is done once on a cell and that's it. As if you would paint the cell green or set the font to bold. And if you write the cell formulas using VBA, just use the property `.NumberFormat`.